# How can I repair access to the Windows 8 recovery (maybe EFI issue?)

Tags: windows-8, efi

Notebook is ASUS G55VW (1 ssd, 1 hdd)

issue is already described here
http://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?28454-G55VW-F9-not-working-after-restore-WIN-8

to sum:
1. I backuped whole system with Paragon Image Backup for Windows 8
2. Win 7 was installed
3. I decided to restore Win 8 installation from backup made before (whole filesystem structure)
4. Win 8 is working, but F9 button to reinstall the system from hidden recovery partition is not working + when I try to reinstall Win 8 from Windows enviroment always ends with an error (launch recovery enviroment etc)

I do not know if this is related information for problem solving

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  sk-SK
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {64806be5-4b9c-11e2-a64a-d1628b6b40c4}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 8
locale                  sk-SK
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {64806be7-4b9c-11e2-a64a-d1628b6b40c4}
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {64806be5-4b9c-11e2-a64a-d1628b6b40c4}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
detecthal               Yes
quietboot               No

C:\Windows\system32>
```

pls assist, ty

Answer (score 1):

This system shipped with Win8 and UEFI?  If so, <kbd>F9</kbd> should never have worked, as the boot process is [too fast to interrupt](http://www.theverge.com/2012/5/23/3038269/windows-8-fast-boot-no-interrupt).

Instead of the old way of interrupting, and running something from a recovery partition, Win8 systems should be [reset](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc)

Of the half dozen different laptops with Win8 on them that I've dealt with, none of them have you pressing an F-key to interrupt the boot to restore; instead you need to access the UEFI boot menu, which will have system restore, recovery, alternate boot, etc. options.

Comment: hi ernie, F9 worked before
plus what I wrote that from Windows enviroment reset is not working, always end with an error - there are several ways to reinstall Win 8 (as mentioned in link you posted), but none works here since restore

Comment: @user193530 I'm not sure how it ever worked; as stated, UEFI Win8 systems do not support using the keyboard to interrupt the boot process

Comment: I do not need F9 to work in case I persuade Windows to see restore partition and to be able to reinstall from Windows enviroment

Comment: @user193530 So did you try to reset using the information from the second link I provided?  In other words, boot into the UEFI menu, and select reset from the Win8 menus . . .

Comment: @user193530 - You sure your recover partition contains what you think it does?

Answer (score 0):

```
Reagentc /setosimage /path E:\RecoveryImage /index 1 /target C:\Windows
```

E:\RecoveryImage should contain your install.wim copied from your recovery partition. (normally not assigned a drive letter, folders often hidden)